# Pinyin on Trusty

Tags: ibus, pinyin

I know that this isn't the first message about pinyin and Trusty (and I fear it won't be the last) but I have no clue about how to solve this problem.

I've installed both simplified and traditional chinese language support, I've set up IBUS to use pinyin and sunpinyin, I've also (as an old message suggested) uninstalled (purged) IBUS and both libpinyin files and reinstalled them but no way to see the IBUS icon on gnome panel. Btw, I'm using gnome-fallback as wm, but is the same if I use Unity or Gnome classic: no icon at all, so no way to change input source. Using  keyboard shortcuts has the same effects: super+space or maj+super+space makes me just to change keyboard layout from italian - my primary language - to polytonic greek (I need sometimes to write in ancient greek so I've configured a greek keyboard too) but no way to get pinyin working or at least to see the input method changer on menubar.

I've workarounded (if it's possible to call what I did a workaround) the problem by installing Precise on an HD parition, so when I need to use pinyin, I've just to boot into Precise, but that's anyway a pain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and have a nice day,

Silvia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when moving from Ubuntu 12 to 14. I had little luck with various ibus-xxx (re)install/remove  . If you don't have to use ibus-pinyin, then [this post](https://blogs.fsfe.org/stefan.a/2014/09/23/set-up-fcitx-chinese-and-japanese-language-input-ubuntu-14-04/) on fcitx worked well for me.

> sudo apt-get install fcitx fcitx-pinyin fcitx-sunpinyin fcitx-googlepinyin

Then run "Input Method" from Application (same as

> im-config

on commandline). After some prompts, select fcitx (from ibus).

After re-login or reboot, click on the keyboard icon, then "Configure Current Input Method",  click on "+", uncheck "Only Show Current Language", search for "Chinese" (case-sensitive!) and choose your favorite pinyin method (I used google-pinyin).

To switch to the pinyin method, use Ctrl+Space. If needed, click on the new pinyin icon (e.g. "g" for google-pinyin) for further configuration. e.g. Toggle between tradition and simplified chinese.

--EDIT-- (March 16, 2016)

Finding my own post exactly one year later with exactly the same issue on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 (one on Macbook; the other on PC to remove Win 8 completely). Google pinyin was usable but the word choice and order were strange to me, and it often failed to type on Google Chrome's own search bar.

So I landed on ibus-libpinyin (not ibus-pinyin) , one of which is called "Chinese (Intelligence Pinyin)" in Text Entry (see below), and documented it here (so I might remember it a year later)

1. Go to System Settings -> Language Support -> Install/Remove Languages, and select/install Chinese (simplified or traditional). Ensure the "Keyboard input method system" is IBus.
2. On a Terminal

> sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
>
> ibus-daemon -drx

3. Go to System Settings -> Text Entry -> "+" and search for "Chinese". The entry "Chinese (Intelligence Pinyin)" should now appear. Add the method.
4. To toggle between the input method, it is now Super + Space.
   The "Super" key is the key with Windows logo on my PC keyboard and the Command Key on my macbook.

Re-login may be necessary if at first the input method behave erratically.

Comment: Thanks, SYK; your solution resolved my problem, even if ibus on 14.04 still doesn't work.

Silvia